# Cocoon callbacks after form reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am creating a form where a user can add many nested questions, and each question can have many nested answers, other fields have ActiveRecord validators and when they fail, the page gets reloaded, the inserted fields are still there.

All callbacks(such as `cocoon:before-insert`) are not reloaded, for instance a change handler of a dropdown on an inserted object

What can I do to make these callbacks be respected if the page is reloaded on a server-side validator fail?

On another note, what would be, code-quality wise, the best way to add handlers created inside a cocoon callback to nested objects built when the `new` method on the controller is called(i.e. objects which are not affected by after-insert/before-insert callbacks)?

Here's some sample coffeescript code for clarification:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#questions').on("cocoon:after-insert", (e, added_question) ->
    added_question.find('#type').change ->
      if $(this).val() is "1"
        added_question.find("#answers").hide()
      else
        added_question.find("#answers").show()
```

EDIT: changed question since removal problem was a lack of a proper wrapper-class

EDIT #2: added sample code

Comment: How do you define the callback handling? In a document ready event? Can you show some code? Are you using rails 4?

Comment: Yes, its in a document ready event, I have added the code for some clarification, what happens is the change handler on the div #type is no longer bound to the object, and yes, using rails 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using rails4, you are using [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), and you can no longer rely on the `document.ready` event, instead you should listen to the `page:change` event.

So your code would become:

```
$(window).bind 'page:change', () ->
  $('#questions').on("cocoon:after-insert", (e, added_question) ->
    added_question.find('#type').change ->
      if $(this).val() is "1"
        added_question.find("#answers").hide()
      else
        added_question.find("#answers").show()
```

alternatively you could write `$(document).on 'page:change', () -> ...` which is imho identical.

[UPDATE: alternative solution]

I had not really read the event handler :) A few remarks:

- you might need to try with `before-insert`. That might work.
- secondly, you are using an *id* `#type`, but there will be more than one a page? That is asking for trouble :) If you are getting more than one, use a class. Also, use a more descriptive name.

There is a simpler solution: jquery can bind dynamically, so you can write

```
$('#questions').on 'change', '.question-type', () -> 
  var this = $(this)
  var question = $(this).parent('.your-question-class')
  question.toggle()
```

Not sure if you really need to check for the value, just toggle the visibility?

This code is of course not tested, but I hope you get the gis of it. Look up the jquery `on` handler, it allows to catch events with a selector. So in this case, any change event inside the `#questions` div, on an element with class `question-type` (instead of your incorrect `#type` id) will be handled by this handler. It will by dynamic, since it is attached to the container element. So if questions are added or removed, it is still valid.

Comment: Actually I was not using turbolinks but made the switch to try this, while the $(window).bind now works, the change handler is still not applied to an existing object, example: I insert a Q1 via cocoon and alter the #type div, thus causing the change callback to fire, then I submit the form with errors, the page changes, but the Q1 object is not inserted, its maintained, therefore, while the after-insert callback still exists and works for new objects, it does not fire for objects created prior to page changing

Comment: The parents method is just what I needed, thank you, as for the toggle, this was just sample code as my actual code has a little bit more to it, but I'll look into it, thank you!

Comment: This was working but I had issues with multiple entries with turbolinks(like issue #177 on cocoon's github page), so I followed suit and changed the include tag to the header and that fixed it, however, the change handler bound to the questions id no longer works, any ideas why?